# New Incognito Window in Firefox 20+ with Selenium (Java)

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, incognito-mode

I have some problem with running my automation test after update of FF to the version 20+. My test worked with Selenium and Firefox 19. So I launched new incognito window in FF 19 with code described in  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Supporting_private_browsing_mode  in **Turning private browsing on and off** section. But it doesn't work with Firefox 20+
Error with text: "Cannot modify properties of a WrapperNative" is displayed all time. So how should I change my Java code to run Firefox in normal mode then open new incognito tab and make tests. I cannot use `browser.privatebrowsing.autostart`

Comment: Why do you need private browsing? Unless you specify a Firefox profile, the original sandbox will remain untouched. WebDriver will always run in a new, clean FF instance. It will not store browsing history.

Comment: Certain implementations of Firefox launch in private mode by default, so testing this case is crucial if such an implementation is used.